# What does Topojson example data mean?

Tags: json, d3.js, topojson

I'm new to d3.js and I want to create a map with TopoJSON, here is the problem when I read the json file in examples, like the following in us.json.

```
    "counties": {
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "geometries": [{
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "arcs": [
                [
                    [0, 1, 2, 3]
                ]
            ],
            "id": 53073
        }, {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "arcs": [
                [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
            ],
            "id": 30105
        }
```

what dose those integer numbers mean? And except for **counties**, there are also **land** and **arcs** which confuses me completely!

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because TopoJSON is an extension of GeoJSON, here are a couple of links that you should use for reference:

- [The GeoJSON Format Specification](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html).
- [The TopoJSON specification](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Specification)

Regarding you specific points in your question:

- about geometry objects: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Specification#geometry-objects
- about arcs: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Specification#arcs-and-coordinates

Comment: I think I've figured it out. But I still wonder how can I transform my own data to topojson format easily? I mean the transformation is a little complex. isn't it?

Comment: the process of using ogr2ogr and topojson is not very user friendly, but once you learn all the basic functions you are ready to go for most of the stuff you could do i think